# Nginx Default Sever Config

Tags: web-server

By mistake I deleted the default sever configuration in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`. Now the sever will not start.

Can someone please tell me what it is so fix it?

Comment: If you have not made other changes after installing you could reinstall the package.

Comment: i did make some changes, but nothing too major. Is there a command to reinstall the package?

Comment: How is this question (as currently described) related to Raspberry Pi rather than specific to nginx?

Answer (score 1):

The file you deleted was a link to the file in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` if you happened to have deleted the actual file that's what the below is for, incase someone else needs it in the future. You need to just recreate the link from the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` folder to the `/etc/nginx/sites-available` folder.

I believe you can use this to link the original `/etc/nginx/sites-available`:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/default /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

If you happened to have deleted the file `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` you can recreate it with the following:

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##      
# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

# SSL configuration
#
# listen 443 ssl default_server;
# listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
#
# Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
# Don't use them in a production server!
#
# include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

root /var/www/html;

# Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name _;

location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
#location ~ \.php$ {
#   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
#
#   # With php5-cgi alone:
#   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
#   # With php5-fpm:
#   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
#}

# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
#location ~ /\.ht {
#   deny all;
#}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

That is the original file in version Nginx 1.6.2 in the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` folder named `default` with no file extension. You will have to use:

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

to write to this directory and recreate the file.

Answer (score 1):

The universal way to restore the default configuration is to run

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confask install package
```

This command will reinstall the package, prompting to replace any configuration files you may have modified or deleted.